# How to get the second half of a list from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
import random
cards = {"Ace" : (1, 11), "numberedCard" : random.randint(2, 10), "Jack" : 11, "Queen" : 12, "King" : 13}
playerDeck = [random.choice(list(cards.keys())), random.choice(list(cards.keys()))]
print("You have been dealt a", playerDeck[0], "and a", playerDeck[1])
total = playerDeck[0] + playerDeck[1]
print("Your total is:", total)
```

so how do i get the numbers designated for the ace, king, queen, jack for the total making

Comment: `cards[playerDeck[0]]` and `cards[playerDeck[1]]`. But that won't work for `Ace`, since its value is a tuple, not a number.

Comment: You need to handle the case of Ace specially, since you have to print all the possible values.

Comment: Also, the numbered card needs to be randomized each time you select a card, not once when creating the `cards` dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to get the game working. This is a basic option (no seeds).

I'd suggest to use a uniform dictionary, instead of a mixture of tuples, functions and integers..

For example, map the cards to their values (ace to 1, then manage value 11 as special case, or viceversa):

```
cards_values = { 'Ace' : 1, 'Two' : 2, 'Three' : 3, 'Four' : 4, 'Five' : 5, 'Six' : 6, 'Seven' : 7, 'Eight' : 8, 'Nine' : 9, 'Ten' : 10, 'Jack' : 10, 'Queen' : 10, 'King' : 10 }
```

Then, when you pick a card from a deck (letting apart seeds) you should consider to **avoid to pick a card twice**. One option is to define a list of available cards, then **shuffle** the deck and **pop** a card. Once you pop the card, append it to the player deck.

**For example:**

```
deck = list(cards_values.keys())
player_deck = []

n = 3 # or whatever cards you like
print("You have been dealt a:")

for _ in range(n):
  random.shuffle(deck)
  card = deck.pop()
  player_deck.append(card)
  print(card)
```

If you print the decks you'll see that `deck` is missing the `n` cards in `player_deck`:

```
print (deck) #=> ['Queen', 'Jack', 'Ten', 'Three', 'King', 'Two', 'Four', 'Nine', 'Five', 'Seven']
print (player_deck) #=> ['Six', 'Ace', 'Eight']
```

**Get the score** mapping the `player_deck` to `cards_values` (I did not take in account the possible value of 11 for the ace):

```
sum([ cards_values[card] for card in player_deck ])
```

Comment: omg, thanks! I will include the stuff to change the ace dw :)